# Android DialogFragment Navigation Crash/Issue

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-components

I have a dialog navigation graph that works fine if I dont dismiss dialogs while navigating to another. But then, the dialog I navigate from doesnt disappear from the screen. If i dismiss them while navigating the app crashes.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val navHostFragment = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.dialogNavigation) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener{
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_retryConnectionDialog_to_batteryDialog)
            dismiss()
        }
    }
```

This is the part of the code (within RetryConnectionDialog.kt) that produces such reactions, any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dismiss your dialog when moving to your new destination, you must do that as part of your `navigate()` action by using [`popUpTo`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) on your `action_retryConnectionDialog_to_batteryDialog` - `dismiss` is an asynchronous operation that happens only after your `navigate()` call happens, which means it is too late to remove it from the back stack (as your new `BatteryDialog` is already stacked on top of it).

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_retryConnectionDialog_to_batteryDialog"
        app:destination="@id/batteryDialog"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/retryConnectionDialog"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the navigation graph, which had not been provided, this might rather be:

```
navController.navigateUp()
navController.navigate(R.id.action_retryConnectionDialog_to_batteryDialog)
```

Comment: By calling `navigateUp()`, you synchronously return back to the previous destination. That means any actions, like `action_retryConnectionDialog_to_batteryDialog` that are associated with the `retryConnectionDialog` no longer become available, so this approach doesn't work (and this exactly what `popUpTo` is for).